# How complex is Drag/Drop implementation in java desktop apps

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I'm working on software specifications at the moment and just want to get an idea if this would be an easy/hard thing to implement.

What I'd like to do is to be able to move items(rows?) between two listbox(grid?) type controls on the same dialog; no external drag/drop support is needed.  In .net apps drag/drop implementation tended to be messy and painful, and I remember MFC being even worse.  Is the situation any better in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not bad at all. Have a look at the [tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html). To start with, see the code for [Basic DnD demo](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/basicdemo.html), which basically covers what you are looking for. The only thing you have to figure out is exactly what data is packaged for the drag-drop. The right choice will depend on whether you plan to support data from outside your form to be dropped in.

Comment: plus examples http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/1780__Drag-Drop.htm and http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/JDK-6/Drag-and-Drop.htm